# TypeScript output still uses Array.prototype.reduce even though I target ES3

Tags: typescript

I was playing around with TypeScript a bit and found a little oddity. Let's say I am building a little application that (sadly) needs to support IE8, too. So I set the TypeScript-compiler to target ES3.

I assumed I could safely use ECMAScript 5.1 goodies such as `Array.prototype.reduce` in my .ts file and that TypeScript will take care of including some kind of polyfill for that. This does not seem to be the case, though:

```
function joinStuff (stuff : string[], joiner : string = ' ') {
    return stuff.reduce((previous, current) => 
        previous ? previous + joiner + current : current
    ) || '';
}
```

will get compiled into:

```
function joinStuff(stuff, joiner) {
    if (joiner === void 0) { joiner = ' '; }
    return stuff.reduce(function (previous, current) {
        return previous ? previous + joiner + current : current;
    }) || '';
}
```

Now this is **not** ECMAScript 3 compatible code! (and it won't run in IE8, of course). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't shim or polyfill any APIs for you. There are lots of readily available polyfill libraries for this purpose.

Comment: I know there's a good polyfill just around every corner. It's just sad that TS silently pumps out non-ES3 code even though you ask it to do so ;)

Comment: Think of it as the ES3 *language* target if that helps :)

Comment: Here is an example using a slightly modified version of the MDN polyfill (there was one small TypeScript compiler error): http://bit.ly/1xVzYOc

Comment: BTW: Babel also doesn't transpile or shim APIs (e.g. 'Promise').
A bit of a shame when you just want stuff to work without maintaining extra dependencies.