# TypeScript - When to use target version?

Tags: typescript

I am having a difficulty understanding what the meaning of the `tsc` target version is (ES3 versus ES5).

In [TypeScript output still uses Array.prototype.reduce even though I target ES3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408343/typescript-output-still-uses-array-prototype-reduce-even-though-i-target-es3#comment41465401_26408400) it says one should read it as a language spec, but doesn't clear things up a lot. As far as I have tried, setting the `--target` doesn't have any effect of the output nor the warning/error messages.

Am I correct to think that this option is to support a Visual Studio feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript and the compiler therefore only touches non-JavaScript bits, which need to be replaced by JavaScript code. The "target" flag is only used to tell the compiler which features it may use here. For example, [TypeScript classes with property accessors will not compile if you target ES3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811034/targeting-es5-with-typescript-in-visual-studio) as the compiler is not able to transform the TypeScript bits of

```
class Foo {
    public get bar(): string {
        return 'Bar';
    }
}
```

into valid ES3 JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.reduce` is an API. The TypeScript compiler provides no API. A TypeScript developer needs to know JavaScript and its API. In the same way as CoffeeScript: "It's just JavaScript".

For example, in a TS code, the API `Array.prototype.reduce` can be used, then the code converted to the ES3 syntax. It will work on IE8 with [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim).